# Android 4.0 bug with MediaRecorder

Tags: android, mediarecorder, android-mediarecorder

I have an application, which turns recording from mic when I have outgoing or incoming call on my phone...

```
                 mRecorder = new MediaRecorder();
                 mRecorder.reset();
               //  mRecorder.setAudioSource(MediaRecorder.AudioSource.VOICE_CALL);
                 mRecorder.setAudioSource(MediaRecorder.AudioSource.MIC);
                 mRecorder.setOutputFormat(MediaRecorder.OutputFormat.THREE_GPP);
                 mRecorder.setOutputFile(mFileName);
                 mRecorder.setAudioEncoder(MediaRecorder.AudioEncoder.AMR_NB);

                 try {
                    mRecorder.prepare();
                } catch (IllegalStateException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }

                 mRecorder.start();
```

It works on Android 2.xxx, now I have tryed to use it on HTC with android 4.0 and was surprised.... everything seems to work good.... But... recordings which were made are simply empty... At the beginning of it there is a sound for a second and then silence))) In LOG I have seen something like ...

```
09-19 14:10:36.462: INvAudioALSADevice(143): getMicMute state=F
09-19 14:10:36.462: INvAudioALSADevice(143): setMicMute state=F
```

I have found info about android interface on: 
        http://www.kandroid.org/online-pdk/guide/classandroid_1_1AudioHardwareInterface.html#_details 
        How can I win this BUG????

Comment: That AudioHardwareInterface reference is very outdated (not that it matters much, because you can't access it directly from an app anyway). Does it work if you set VOICE_CALL as the audio source? I've seen implementations that won't record anything during a voice call unless you use the VOICE_CALL audio source. You could also try recording 8 kHz or 16 kHz PCM data with an AudioRecord object and see if that works. Then there's the possibility HTC's ICS ROM simply doesn't support this usecase.

Comment: Yes, you are right! VOICE_CALL works not at all devices... that's why I use MIC....I'll try to set PCM 8 and 16... But I am more and more sure that the problem is in HTC ROMs...((